# Computationally efficient date addition (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with ~42,000,000 rows and 6 columns. The index column is a timestamp, and there exists a date column of type datetime64 ("`data['settle']`"). I'm trying to run the following code to add a business day to the date if the 'holiday' column returns "1".

```
for i in range(len(data['settle'])-1):
    if data['holiday'].iloc[i] == 1:
        data['settle'].iloc[i] = data['settle'].iloc[i] + pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(1)
    else:
        pass
```

The only issue is that this takes a very long time to return anything (over 30 minutes!) and I'm running it on decent hardware. I can't split this to more hardware via spark or similar solution as this is an enterprise environment. How might I make this code run more quickly?

Comment: You must be brave to use pandas with 42 million rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done by `.loc`

```
data.loc[data['holiday']==1,'settle'] += pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(1)
```

Comment: Very easy. Took ~1 minute. Obviously need to hone my coding skills. Thanks!

Comment: @Fomalhaut-C yw:-) happy coding